# WordPress blog date function

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a WordPress blog theme created by someone named Scott Wallick.  [Here](http://scottwallick.com/portfolio/web-design/) is his website.  FYI, I'm using the "Barthelme" theme.

Anyway, this theme prints out the date as follows:  August 5, 2009 is displayed as "2009 08 05".  I would like to change the display to the following format: 5 Aug 2009.

How do I do this?

I found the function below in the WordPress code.  Could I just somehow change the code below to make it do what I asked above?  If so, what changes should I make?

```
function barthelme_date_classes($t, &$c, $p = '') {
    $t = $t + (get_option('gmt_offset') * 3600);
    $c[] = $p . 'y' . gmdate('Y', $t);
    $c[] = $p . 'm' . gmdate('m', $t);
    $c[] = $p . 'd' . gmdate('d', $t);
    $c[] = $p . 'h' . gmdate('h', $t);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
function barthelme_date_classes($t, &$c, $p = '') {
    $t = $t + (get_option('gmt_offset') * 3600);
    $c[] = $p . 'j' . gmdate('j', $t);
    $c[] = $p . 'M' . gmdate('M', $t);
    $c[] = $p . 'Y' . gmdate('Y', $t);
    $c[] = $p . 'h' . gmdate('h', $t);
}
```

I just changed the order in which every date element is stored, and used the format you asked for.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't change anything... any other ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the Barthelme theme, line 23 of index.php reads

```
<span class="entry-date">
<abbr class="published" title="<?php the_time('Y-m-d\TH:i:sO'); ?>">
<?php unset($previousday); printf(__('%1$s', 'barthelme'), the_date('Y m d', false)) ?>
</abbr>
</span>
```

Change it to

```
<span class="entry-date">
<abbr class="published" title="<?php the_time('Y-m-d\TH:i:sO'); ?>">
<?php unset($previousday); printf(__('%1$s', 'barthelme'), the_date('j M Y', false)) ?>
</abbr>
</span>
```